# Azerothcore: Gameobject (GUID: , Entry: ) not created. Suggested coordinates isn't valid

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I got this error in the console when I drop the flag in a battleground CTF (like Twin Peaks).

> Gameobject (GUID: 2134732 Entry: 179786) not created. Suggested coordinates isn't valid (X: 1568.691895 Y: 348.233307)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure that you've extracted maps, vmaps & mmaps for this map. (I think maps are enough)